# Install button in Software Center is disabled

Tags: software-recommendation

For some unknown reasons Install button is disabled in Software Center and therefore I am unable to install any software from Software Center. But it is possible to install software using command `apt-get install package_name`.

I have Internet connection through 3G modem but I think Software Center doesn't have internet because it shows a notification saying 'No network connection' (Sin conexión de red).

In the screenshot below you can see the problem I have described:

[image]

**EDIT 1**

When I run it from terminal with `software-center` command it outputs following messages:

```
2011-12-28 22:31:30,618 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.em - INFO - EM's: 17 15 21
2011-12-28 22:31:31,028 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2011-12-28 22:31:31,102 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.utils - INFO - Softwarecenter style provider for ambiance Gtk theme: /usr/share/software-center/ui/gtk3/css/softwarecenter.css
2011-12-28 22:31:32,513 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - software-center-agent finished with status 0
```

Comment: Can you run the software-center from the command line and tell us of any output?.

Comment: @JavierRivera. Thnx for trying to help me. I have added what you had asked in the question part under "EDIT 1" section. Anything else pls let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I can find nothing useful on that output.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor - please can you post the contents of `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` ?

Comment: are you using any proxy server(ex squid)? See on network proxy settings.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 6):

I've also had csome problems. Re-installing software center can't fix it.

You have an alternate solution. Just look at the top left of this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrBy5.png and you will get it.

You can't click the install button because it seems inactive/disabled, so just go to the top left and find **file -> install**. I hope this will help you.

[image: screenshot-menu-install]

Comment: I thought this bug is fixed in 12.04 :( ,I am having same issue So I am using above method

Comment: Running the Software Center using 'Alt+F2' and typing `gksu software-center` to run the software center and the above solution worked for me. [(source)](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1340014&page=2)