# Can't install anything in Software Center

Tags: 12.04, software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software center not opening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185117/software-center-not-opening)

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my system and I can't install anything from the software center. When I click the install button nothing happens at all. No error, just doesn't work. I originally had [these issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107034/cannot-install-anything-in-ubuntu-software-center) but the solution listed there worked for me. Installing packages from the command line with apt-get and dpkg works. I also tried following the advice in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1340014) but to no avail.

Edit: Running from the command line I get no messages when I try and click the install button but get a warning when it's started:

```
2012-05-06 12:14:04,481 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2012-05-06 12:14:04,536 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2012-05-06 12:14:04,988 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
```

Edit 2: Seems I slightly stupid and just realized that it's disabled out (guess I'm not used to the Ubuntu GUI yet). Realizing this I googled and found [this workaround](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90734/install-button-in-software-center-is-disabled), but still does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: You could try and launch the ``software-center`` from the Terminal and the log messages (which are printed on the Terminal when you click on "Install" in the USC) might provide some clues.

Comment: Try doing a fresh installation of Software Centre from Synaptic Manager.

Comment: My problem was fixed by getting new internet. I posted this as a solution and marked it but it was deleted for some reason.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a duplicate of a question that was asked 4 months later.

Answer (score 2):

Since the install button won't work, instead select the software you want to install by clicking on File on the top menu, and click "Install", and see if it will work.

Comment: I actually found that work around and mentioned it in my second edit. This is still not a true solution as it does not solve the problem. I believe it is a network related issue because getting new internet fixed it and it can no longer be replicated.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was solved by doing

```
sudo software-center
```

in the terminal, essentially just starting it with the "right" privileges. Hops this solves your problem as well. Good luck

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that with no avail.