# install / remove button disabled on software center

Tags: 14.04, software-center

upgraded to 14.04 lts from 12.04 lts.

issue is install / remove button is disabled in software center so can't install or remove software from software center.

how to fix it?

Comment: Open terminal and enter "sudo apt-get update " without quotes.

Comment: In Software center, you can't click the install button because it seems to be inactive/disabled. Go to the top left and find file -> install.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:
1.Try reinstalling software center
(before reinstalling be sure to update the source list)
sudo apt-get purge software-center
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-center

2. If reinstalling doesn't help look at this one - [Install button in Software Center is disabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90734/install-button-in-software-center-is-disabled)

Comment: i tried both options before posting here. didn't work. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type `sudo software-center`. The Software Center now launched will still have the install button disabled, but the File/Intall menu will be enabled. My system: 14.04 LTS (latest updates).

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicated answer.As you said it is upgraded from 12.04 it should be a bug:
[Install button in Software Center is disabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90734/install-button-in-software-center-is-disabled) .